# C# DateTime MySQL Command

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having issues with using the DateTime as the parameter to work for a sql query.

Here is the query I would like :

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT idGameNumber FROM GameOutcome WHERE GameOutcome.gameDate = <insert DateTime game_time>";
```

where game_time is a DateTime object and Gameoutcome.gameDate is a DATETIME datatype.

What do I need to put on the right side of the = sign in there WHERE clause?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**  using `DateTime` string

MYSQL takes the `DateTime` in Following default format:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

so you can convert your `datetime` object into above `format`.

Try This:

```
command.CommandText ="SELECT idGameNumber FROM GameOutcome WHERE GameOutcome.gameDate ='"+ game_time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")+"'";
```

**Solution 2:** using `parameterised queries`.

you might have already heared about `parameterised queries`.
Parameterised queries not only avoid `sql injection attacks` they also provide clean way of sending/passing `arguments` to feilds in the table.

```
command.CommandText ="SELECT idGameNumber FROM GameOutcome WHERE GameOutcome.gameDate =@gamedate;"    
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamedate",game_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

as datetime format in mysql is in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format so to use c# `DateTime` and pass it in query `where` as parameter:

1. you can use `ToString()` method of `DateTime` variable and format the returned value as: `game_time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

```
command.CommandText = $"SELECT idGameNumber FROM GameOutcome WHERE GameOutcome.gameDate = '{game_time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}'";
```

or you can write the interpolation simpler as:

```
command.CommandText = $"SELECT idGameNumber FROM GameOutcome WHERE GameOutcome.gameDate = '{game_time:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}'";
```

the longer version to use:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo isoFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

dateValue.ToString(isoFormat.SortableDateTimePattern); 

dateValue.ToString(isoFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
```