# problem on formatting DateTime in parametised query

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to parametise my queries, and I meet some problems with a DateTime parameter, and have the following error `Datetime function: datetime field overflow`.

Here is my insert function in my object :

```
private MySqlParameter[] getListMySqlParams()
{
    MySqlParameter[] listParams = new MySqlParameter[]
    {
        new MySqlParameter("id", this.id),
        new MySqlParameter("name", this.name),
        new MySqlParameter("sourceAssembly", this.sourceAssembly.Name),
        new MySqlParameter("idContract", this.contrat.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("idPhase", this.fase.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("mountingDate", this.mountingDate),
        new MySqlParameter("mountingPosition", this.mountingPosition),
        new MySqlParameter("guid", this.guid),
        new MySqlParameter("idSourceAssembly", this.sourceAssembly.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("indice", this.ind),
        new MySqlParameter("erreur", this.erreur),
        new MySqlParameter("completed", this.completed),
        new MySqlParameter("idOperation", this.idOperation),
        new MySqlParameter("idNextOperation", this.idNextOperation),
        new MySqlParameter("comm", this.comm),
        new MySqlParameter("treatment", this.treatment),
        new MySqlParameter("priority", this.priority),
        new MySqlParameter("weight", this.weight),
        new MySqlParameter("dateStart", this.dateStart),
        new MySqlParameter("dateLastModify", this.dateLastModify),
        new MySqlParameter("listAssRevisionDetail", this.listAssRevisionDetail.ConvertToString()),
    };
    return listParams;
}
public void Insert()
{
    insert();
}
private void insert()
{
    DBConnect DataBase = new DBConnect();
    string query = "INSERT INTO [vsteel].unique_assembly(NAME,NAME_SOURCE,ID_CONTRACT,ID_PHASE,MOUNTING_DATE,MOUNTING_POS,GUID,ID_ASS,IND,IS_ERROR,COMPLETED," +
        "ID_OP,ID_OP_NEXT,COMMENT,TREATMENT,PRIORITY,WEIGHT,DATE_START,DATE_LAST_MODIFY,LIST_REVISIONS) " +
        "VALUES(@name,@sourceAssembly,@idContract,@idPhase,@mountingDate,@mountingPosition,@guid,@idSourceAssembly,@indice,@erreur,@completed," + 
        "@idOperation,@idNextOperation,@comm,@treatment,@priority,@weight,@dateStart,@dateLastModify,@listAssRevisionDetail)";
    this.id = DataBase.InsertNew(query,this.getListMySqlParams());
}
```

Then my DBConnect class :

```
public long InsertNew(string query, MySqlParameter[] myParamArray)
{
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        long lastId = -1;
        using (this.connection)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[vsteel].", ""), connection))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myParamArray.Count(); i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(myParamArray[i]);
                }
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;

            }
        }
        return lastId;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Before using parametised queries, I formatted myself the date as the following :

`value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

But as I understood, now parametised queries may do it by itself ([stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531706/c-sharp-datetime-mysql-command))
In debug mode I can see both dates are set to `{27.09.2021 22:16:00}`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Well what are the actual values of `dateStart` and `dateLastModified`? When you say "I can see both dates are set to [...]" - where do you mean? In the parameter list, in the database, in the variables?

Comment: (It's also very unclear why you've got two methods which only vary in the case of the first character, where the first calls the second...)

Comment: @JonSkeet in the variables, and in the parameters (`MySqlParameter`). In the database it has not been inserted as I have the message error on the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`(forgot to say)

Comment: @JonSkeet well about method names, you can ignore the first, it is just the public method calling the private one, isn't it correct to do so?

Comment: u shouldnt need to format the date...just pass in a date as a "DateTime" data type

Comment: you can...so the "ToString()" thing isnt needed... this.dateStart should be a DateTime

Comment: @Ctznkane525 ok I think I got confused, I used `ToString()` thing before (when I didn't use parametised queries), now I don't use it anymore. I send them as `DateTime`.

Comment: It appears that MySQL cannot support dates before the year 1000 AD. .NET DateTimes default to being 01/01/0001. If you have a date field that you've failed to set to an appropriate actual datetime, I think you'd see this error

Comment: So, for both `DateTime`, they are set at DateTime.Now, so `{27.09.2021 22:42:17}` I see the format used is not the same as in database, but as I understood this is not the problem?

Comment: After checking, I didn't notice one of the dates is set to DateTime.MaxValue (`{31.12.9999 23:59:59}`) this may be an issue?

Comment: the data type in the database should match the field yes...class definition and table definition should help explain that

Comment: @Ctznkane525 yes they are the same type (DateTime)

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I found the issue thanks, the problem is MySql can store values up to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. DateTime.MaxValue is actually 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999. her is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871215/datetime-maxvalue-saves-as-zero-in-mysql.
I think I can close the question, thanks for your help

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks you put me on the direction... DateTime.MaxValue also is not accepted by MySql (see link in previous comment).